# Mysql query to decide the type if group by value is greater than 1 consider as type 2 else 1

Tags: mysql, case

I want to write a case condition in mysql query when grouped by channelvalue if the count is more than 1 it is considered as type_id 3 if there is no duplicates for the channelvalue then the type_id should be 2
else 0

```
select b.ChannelValue
case
when count(*),ChannelValue from tableb group by ChannelValue having count(*)=1 then 2
when count(*),ChannelValue from tableb group by ChannelValue having count(*)>1 then 3
else 0 END  AS type_id
from tablea a inner join tableb b
on a.ChannelValue = b.ChannelValue;
```

Help me out !

Comment: Provide some sample data (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) and desired output for it with explanations. Try to show all possible combinations in sample data. Also specify precise server version.

Comment: *if the count is more than 1 it is considered as type_id 3 if there is no duplicates for the channelvalue then the type_id should be 2* Set these conditions priority. In current state type_id=2 will be set never.

Comment: If you mean "type of data returned" you can wrap your case in a cast statement

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like below:

```
select ChannelValue,
case
when (
  select count(*) from tableb 
  group by tableb.ChannelValue 
  having tableb.ChannelValue = tablea.ChannelValue) = 1 then 2
 when(
  select count(*) from tableb 
  group by tableb.ChannelValue 
  having tableb.ChannelValue = tablea.ChannelValue) > 1 then 3
 else 0
END as type_id
from tablea;
```

Say if you have this test data:

```
INSERT INTO tablea (PersonID, ChannelValue)
VALUES (1, 100),
(2, 200),
(3, 300);

INSERT INTO tableb (testID, ChannelValue, characterid)
VALUES (1, 100, 1),
(2, 100,2),
(3, 300, 3);
```

The query would return:

| ChannelValue | type_id |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 |
| 200 | 0 |
| 300 | 2 |

Comment: The query have no WHERE at all - so the subquery in FROM is more obvious and useful then correlated ones in output list.